# replace all input tag with its value using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Here I am a using regular expression to remove the html input tag. But I have to replace with its value. 
I need to remove the input tag without the value. Result should be
`<td> 15200 </td>` on td tag.

```js
function fnTextValue() {
  var tab_text = "<td><input name='MyTextBox' type='text' value='15200' id='MyTextBoxId'></td>";
  console.log(tab_text);
  
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");
  console.log(tab_text);
}
```

```html
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnTextValue();">
  Text Value
</button>
```

Comment: why use a regex? could you not use `getElementsByTagName` then loop through them and use `replaceWith` or something similar whilst getting their value in the loop?

Comment: Actually my real table is so large that's why i use this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String operation faster than RegEx you can go with @Pete idea. If you really try to solve with regex you can do as follows.

```
tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*value\s*=\s*["'](.+?)["']\s*[^>]*>/,"$1");
```

And the JS solution is

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var x of ele){ 
    if(x){
    var val = x.value;
    var node = document.createTextNode(val); 
    x.after(node);
    x.remove();
}
```